# Дамп первых 10 строк таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Имеем бд, допустим стандартную бд mysql, в ней есть таблица под названием help_keyword. Нужно из этой таблицы сделать дамп первых 10 строк, далее создать бд с названием допустим qwe и положить туда задампленную таблицу из 10 строк из help_keyword. Мои действия:
Выхожу в консоли из mysql и ввожу:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 10" mysql help_keyword > helpp.sql
```

создается sql файл с дампом

далее я делаю следующее:

```
mysql;

create database qwe;

use qwe;

source helpp.sql;
```

А он мне выдает:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 3723 (HY000): The table 'help_keyword' may not be created in the reserved tablespace 'mysql'.
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Собственно вопрос:
Как сделать дамп таблицы из первых 10 строк и поместить эту таблицу в новую бд? Может проблема в том, что я создаю дамп не таблицы а строк?

Comment: И заглянуть в файл helpp.sql запрещает религия?

Comment: Укажите явно имя базы данных (`--databases your_db_name`), которую вы хотите дампить, иначе получите все базы, включая системные

Comment: А можно полностью запрос посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Просто в клиенте командной строки MySQL, не выходя в консоль, выполняешь:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE qwe;
CREATE TABLE qwe.help_keyword 
    SELECT *
    FROM  mysql.help_keyword
    LIMIT 10;
```

И, собственно, всё...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. Если не указан ORDER BY, то скопируется не "первые 10", а "какие-то 10". В таблице вообще нет никакого первый-последний, это несортированная куча.

Comment: А если у меня имеется файл .sql, его как скопировать?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html команда `source`.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я делаю source helps.sql; а он ругается на меня. В сообщении выше лог ошибки

Comment: @RomanBocharov *а он ругается на меня* Ага... и веником замахивается. Если возникает ошибка - следует цитировать полный текст ошибки, без каких-либо урезаний и корректировок.

Comment: В теле сообщения я скопировал полный лог того, чего он мне выдаёт без сокращений

Comment: ERROR 3723 (HY000): The table 'help_keyword' may not be created in the reserved tablespace 'mysql'.
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'qwe.help_keyword' doesn't exist
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: @RomanBocharov Вот стесняюсь спросить... а у Вашей учётной записи, пардон, привилегия на создание базы данных - есть? PS. Скриншот добавил - к командам нареканий быть не должно.

Answer (score 0):

не  " --opt " а " --skip opt "

Comment: так же обратил внимание что кавычки не одинарные в лимите.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос